# Setting VStudio Breakpoint in object instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

Using VStudio 2010 and C#

I have a class called Mammal.  Dog and Cat inherit from Mammal.

A particular dog is barfing however and I need to find out why.

I want to set a breakpoint in the Mammal class - but only when the Dog class is executing and calling Mammal as a base class.  I have lots of instances of dogs and cats - I am looking to set the breakpoint for a particular instance of Dog - called Fido.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Is this possible?  I don't see how a conditional breakpoint is going to help me do this.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't conditional breakpoints help?

Comment: Fido is name and name is in mammal class? if so use conditional breakpoint if not show classes you have

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Condition` on `BreakPoint` to achieve this. `Breakpoint` will only hit when your entered `Condition` is true

See this tutorial [How to: Specify a Breakpoint Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx)

You can use the condition `this is Dog && this.Name == "Fido"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional breakpoint where

```
this is Dog && (this as Dog).Name == "Fido"
```

Comment: Why not use `((Dog) this).Name` ? Imho either be sure it's of type `Dog` and use a normal cast, or use `as` and check for `null` first.

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga in general code I agree, however this is for a condition on a breakpoint and the above reads quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested conditional break points but I've always found them to slow down debugging as the condition is evaluated by the debugger. I usually do the following:-

In your base class add:

```
#if DEBUG
  BreakOnParticularPet ();
#endif
```

wherever you want to stop the program and then add:

```
void BreakOnParticularPet ()
{
  if (this pet is the one we're interested in) // pseudocode 
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break ();
  } 
}
```

Comment: You could also / instead add `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` at the top of the Break method.
However, I myself would not be a big fan of adding this kind of method.

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga: I didn't know about that attribute. Cool. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass Dog to SubDog, and only call `new SubDog` when creating Fido. Set a breakpoint in SubDog's constructor, or override the methods in Dog you need to debug, have the overrides call the base method, and set breakpoints in the overrides.